# bits of jQuery1.3.2 showing up as 404's

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-code-404

I just started using jQuery 1.3.2 on one of my sites - mostly DOM stuff but there's a little bit of ajax. My log records show consistent 404's coming from the folder where I keep the jQuery file, and the 'pages' triggering the error turn out to be snippets of the jQuery file:

- ){F.html(E?o(
- ]||!o.suppo
- rt.htmlSerialize&&[1,

I've scoured my site looking for js errors, but I'm not finding any. But googling these returns nothing (but the jQuery file).

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Corey

Comment: sounds like your web server is possessed! what web server are you using?

Comment: Standard LAMP config. As the guy said below, I imagine the file is just not being delivered correctly or something. Just worried something is breaking for my users!

Answer (score 0):

Have seen those in log files before. Figured they were just attempts at hacking or trying to bring down the site.

Or mayhap the person checking out the site had the jQuery come out garbled for them somehow and left them with spit junk in the code.